# Solution of a initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following problem
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l} \displaystyle\frac{a^{2}+t^{2}}{t^{2}}x'(t)+x(t)=\frac{t^{2020}}{t^{2}}(a^{2}+t^{2}) \\ x(1)=1\end{array}\right.$$
where $a\in\mathbb{R}$, I found that
$$x(t)=e^{-(t-\arctan(t/a))}\cdot\int t^{2020}\cdot e^{t-\arctan(t/a)}dt+c\cdot e^{-(t-\arctan(t/a))}$$
since the integrating factor is
$$\mu(t)=e^{\int\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}+t^{2}}dt}$$

I don't know how to use the fact that $x(1)=1$. Can I just put $t=1$ even inside the integral? How is supposed to be the final solution?

Comment: You cannot substitute $t$ with $1$ inside of the integral, you need to evaluate the integral first.

Comment: @Vasya and how do I evaluate this?

Comment: Looking at the integral, I am not sure it has a solution which can be expressed using elementary functions. I also think that your solution is not quite correct.

Comment: The exponent should be $t-a\,\arctan(t/a)$.